# Angular: Active Slide Number & Total Slides in an Owl Carousel 2.0.7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, owl-carousel

I am new to Angular & using an owl carousel in my application. My catch is to display the index of current slide and total number of slides present in the carousel. The current slide index should change with changing slides. For your reference, my HTML is below:

```
    <div class="carousel-custom-nav">
      <img src="assets/carousel-prev.svg" class="jo-carousel-prev" (click)="carousel.previous()" />
      <p class="mr-ml-10">Active Slide Index / Total No. of Slides</p>
      <img src="assets/carousel-next.svg" class="jo-carousel-next" (click)="carousel.next()" />
    </div>
```

By now you might have understood, I actually want to change the paragraph content with respective numbers.

I tried the owl events available in its documentation but couldn't achieve in angular.

Comment: Just to understand, you did choose  https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2? It is deprecated and not updated since 2018. Did you consider using another lib buld for Angular like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o? If the features you need from the lib are minimal, did you consider to just write an own structural directive?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same because whole project is running this version. Do you have any suggestions which version should I consider?

Comment: As I said, ngx-owl-carousel-o or own structural directive. It is not hard to write those once you understand them. https://medium.com/netanelbasal/understanding-angular-structural-directives-659acd0f67e